# Data from Erddap to Leaflet Velocity map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My organisation uses the Erddap data server to publish oceanographic models. We also use Leaflet to publish web maps and are looking at using the Leaflet Velocity library to create visualisations of modelled sea surface velocity.

The code below creates something that looks like the (not well documented) JSON format expected by Leaflet Velocity, and it seems to parse as I get no errors in my JavaScript Console - but nothing is displaying on the map.

Anyone have any ideas?

```js
    const minLat = 48.5;
    const maxLat = 58.5;
    const minLon = -17.0;
    const maxLon = -2.0;
    const refTime = '2019-12-15T00:00:00Z';
    const spacingLat = 0.025;
    const spacingLon = 0.025;
    const strideLon = 20;
    const strideLat = 20;
    const strideTime = 1;
    var mymap = L.map('map').setView([maxLat-((maxLat-minLat)/2), maxLon-((maxLon-minLon)/2)], 7);
    var gebco = L.tileLayer.wms('https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/2019/mapserv?',{layers: 'gebco_2019_grid'}).addTo(mymap);
    fetch('https://erddap.marine.ie/erddap/griddap/IMI_Model_Stats.json?sea_surface_x_velocity[(' + refTime + '):1:(' + refTime + ')][(' +  String(minLat) + '):' + String(strideLat) + ':(' + String(maxLat) + ')][(' + String(minLon) + '):'+ String(strideLon) +':(' + String(maxLon) + ')],sea_surface_y_velocity[(' + refTime + '):1:(' + refTime + ')][(' + String(minLat) + '):' + String(strideLat)+ ':(' + String(maxLat) + ')][(' + String(minLon) + '):' + String(strideLon) + ':(' + String(maxLon) + ')]').
    then(
        response => response.json()
    ).
    then(
        data => [{
            'header':{
                'la1': maxLat,
                'la2': minLat,
                'lo1': minLon,
                'lo2': maxLon,
                'dx': strideLon * spacingLon,
                'dy': strideLat * spacingLat,
                'nx': [...new Set(data.table.rows.map(x => x[2]))].length,
                'ny': [...new Set(data.table.rows.map(x => x[1]))].length,
                'parameterCategory': 2,
                'parameterNumber': 2,
                'parameterUnit': 'm.s-1',
                'parameterNumberName': data.table.columnNames[3],
                'refTime': refTime.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z','')
            }, 
            'data': data.table.rows.map(x => x[3])
        },{
            'header':{
                'la1': maxLat,
                'la2': minLat,
                'lo1': minLon,
                'lo2': maxLon,
                'dx': strideLon * spacingLon,
                'dy': strideLat * spacingLat,
                'nx': [...new Set(data.table.rows.map(x => x[2]))].length,
                'ny': [...new Set(data.table.rows.map(x => x[1]))].length,
                'parameterCategory': 2,
                'parameterNumber': 3,
                'parameterUnit': 'm.s-1',
                'parameterNumberName': data.table.columnNames[4],
                'refTime': refTime.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z','')
            }, 
            'data': data.table.rows.map(x => x[4])
        }]
    ).then(
    report => {
            //document.getElementById('dump').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(report);
            try{
            var velocityLayer = L.velocityLayer({
                displayValues: true,
                displayOptions: {
                    velocityType: "GBR Water",
                    displayPosition: "bottomleft",
                    displayEmptyString: "No water data"
                },
                data: report,
                maxVelocity: 0.3,
                minVelocity: 0,
                velocityScale: 0.1,
                opacity: 0.97
            }).addTo(mymap);
            document.getElementById('dump').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(report);
            console.log(report);
        } catch(err) {
            document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = err.message;
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I sorted this out and am leaving the link here to a working example of the code

https://irishmarineinstitute.github.io/erddap-leaflet-velocity-demo/

https://github.com/IrishMarineInstitute/erddap-leaflet-velocity-demo

Comment: Not well documented is right! I've been looking everywhere for an explanation of the values in in these JSON files. Thank you.

Comment: Author of `leaflet-velocity` here. I agree it's unfortunate the input format is somewhat exotic, which I regret, however I _did_ make reference to this in the [README](https://github.com/onaci/leaflet-velocity/blob/master/README.md?plain=1#L17) (i.e. it was adopted from [grib2json](https://github.com/cambecc/grib2json), which is a non-standard JSON representation of the [GRIB2 format](https://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/docs/grib2/grib2_doc/)). It would be nice [if CoverageJSON was also supported](https://github.com/onaci/leaflet-velocity/issues/70), PR's welcome 